# Find out whether a period of a time includes any days in December

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause

I met a Oracle SQL problem which says "List captains' last name and first name of those who sailed in month of December." 
What I know is that CAPTAIN is an entity and has attributes of start_date, end_date and other essential attributes. I need to find out that period of time contains any day in December.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

For example:

```
start_date      end_date      result
2019-12-1       2019-12-8     YES
2019-10-1       2019-12-8     YES
2019-12-1       2020-2-8      YES
2019-5-8        2019-5-8      NO
2020-1-5        2020-2-8      NO
2019-11-1       2020-1-8      YES
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the `start_date` and `end_date` columns?

Comment: Do you want december for which year?

Comment: datatype is Date.

Comment: I think it should be december of any year. For example, if start time is 2019.05.01 and end time is 2019.12.5, the answer should be yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select *
from mytable 
where end_date > add_months(trunc(start_date, 'yy'), 11)
```

The logic is, for each `start_date`, to check if the end date is (strictly) greater than the first of December at midnight, on the same year.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f5833d5df8607613e7b774c4efa7d17)** with your sample data:

```
START_DATE | END_DATE 
:--------- | :--------
01-DEC-19  | 08-DEC-19
01-OCT-19  | 08-DEC-19
01-DEC-19  | 08-FEB-20
01-NOV-19  | 08-JAN-20
```

Comment: Since the dates don't show time-of-day, it is possible that an END_DATE of 1 December is considered to mean that the captain did sail "in December". If so, the inequality should be non-strict. Other than that, thumbs up!

Comment: @mathguy: thanks for the positive comment! Yes I was speculating whether the comparison should be exclusive or inclusive... OP can easily fix that according to their exact requirement.